# Magnitude of normal acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

As I am taught in mechanics, normal acceleration is the variation in direction where it is magnitude, for non-linear trajectory is:

$$a_n=(V^2/R)$$
where $V$ is the speed of the object at a given time and $R$ is the radius of curvature.

Can I have a proof for this relation or a hint how it can be proved?

Comment: http://people.sju.edu/~pklingsb/curvature.pdf and many other websites have the proof.

Answer (score 1):

For any body experiencing a uniform circular motion the position $\vec{R}$ can be determined by
$$\vec{R}=|\vec{R}|\cos{\omega t}\hat{x}+|\vec{R}|\sin{\omega t}\hat{y}\\
\Rightarrow \vec{R}^{'}=-\omega |\vec{R}|\sin{\omega t}\hat{x}+\omega|\vec{R}|\cos{\omega t}\hat{y}\\
\Rightarrow \vec{R}^{''}=-\omega^2|\vec{R}|\cos{\omega t}\hat{x}-\omega^2|\vec{R}|\sin{\omega t}=-\omega^2 \vec{R}$$

This is your proof, since $\omega =\frac{V}{R}$ and also since $\vec{a}=\vec{R}^{''}$. Also note that $\vec{a}$ is in the direction of $\vec{R}$, hence this is your normal acceleration $a_n$. Also what is interesting is that since the body is moving with uniform angular velocity $\omega$, the torque acting on the body is zero, but since the body is accelerating the force on the body is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Recognize that instantaneously the object will move in an arc about a center. We can track the position using a coordinate system with $\hat{n}$ radially out, and $\hat{e}$ tangential to the motion

We track the motion with

$$\vec{r} = R\, \hat{n}$$

No we recognize that the direction vectors change over time and if we define the angular speed $\omega = \frac{v}{R}$ that change is

$$ \begin{align} 
\frac{{\rm d} \hat{n}}{{\rm d} t} = \vec{\omega} \times \hat{n} =  \omega\, \hat{e} \\
\frac{{\rm d} \hat{e}}{{\rm d} t} = \vec{\omega} \times \hat{e} =  -\omega\, \hat{n} 
\end{align} $$

Now we can form the velocity vector (using the product rule and $\omega = \frac{v}{R}$)

$\require{cancel}$

$$ \vec{v} = \frac{{\rm d}\,\vec{r}}{{\rm d}t} =\cancel{ \dot{R} \hat{n}} + R\, \omega\,\hat{e} = v\,\hat{e} $$

and the acceleration

$$ \vec{a} = \frac{{\rm d}\,\vec{v}}{{\rm d}t} = \dot{v} \hat{e} + v\,(-\omega \hat{n}) = \dot{v}\, \hat{e} + \frac{v^2}{R} \hat{n}$$

This is the same equation I used in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/83592/392) to demostrate how to go from accelerations to reaction forces.